# Lower and upper bounds

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose A is a nonempty set of real numbers such that p is a lower bound of A and q is an upper bound of A. Prove p less than or equal to q.

I understand that p has to be less than or equal to q because p is a lower bound and q is a upper bound but I don't know the steps in between.

Help please

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is nonempty, then there exists an element $x\in A$.

Since $p$ is a lower bound of $A$, $p\le x$. Since $q$ is an upper bound of $A$, $x \le q$.

By transitivity, $p\le q$.